# Formula to calculate equal % increase for each step between min and max - Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I need there to be an equal % increase for each step in a 6 step from Min to max.

For example I have a min value of 20000 and a max of 40000 and would need to fit as follows:

```
1 - 20000
2 - ?
3 - ?
4-  ?
5 - ?
6 - 40000
```

I need point 2 to have the the same % Increase from step 1 as step 3 has from step 2 etc to reach 40000 on step 6.

I can do this using goal seek but I need it to be a formula.

Comment: What have you tried ? What would be a solution with a simpler exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out I just needed to use a RATE formula